# How to use Typescript Declaration Merging in an Angular CLI project

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

Is there a way I can use typescript declaration merging in an angular cli project?

For example I have two files containing an object:

**fileA.ts**

```
export const objA {
  foo: 'foo',
}
```

**fileB.ts**

```
export const objB {
  bar: 'bar'
}
```

For each of this files I declared a typescript declaration file with the same name for the interface

**fileA.d.ts**

```
interface MyObjectDef {
  foo: string,
}
```

**fileB.d.ts**

```
interface MyObjectDef {
  bar: string
}
```

My question is how can I use the merged interface definition `MyObjectDef` in my angular cli project?

For example in my **app.component.ts**

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <p>Hello</p>
  `,
  styles: []
})
export class AppComponent {

  /*
   * MyObjectDef shoud be a merged definition of both files (fileA and fileB),
   * so I can use myObject.foo and myObject.bar without compiler errors.
   */
  public myObject: MyObjectDef 
}
```

I haven't found any useful answer in the web at all.

It seems to me I have to modify my `tsconfig.json` file to get this work

```html
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

**Background**

I found an interesting [article](https://netbasal.com/better-code-organization-with-angular-di-multi-option-31f691918655) on Medium where typescript merging is used and comes in very handy but I can't get it work.

Answer (score 0):

You shall declare it into the same namespace when in different files/modules.

In the following example I declared it in the `global` namespace but I guess you use any namespace you want.

```
declare global {
  interface MyInterface {
    someLabel: string;
  }
}
```

Reference: [last two sections of declaration merging in TS manual](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html)

Comment: Could you please explain us what do you meaning on "You shall declare it into the same namespace when in different files/modules."?